# Slow UPDATE on SQLITE3 with big blobs (60MB) on python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm making a program to manage a list of components and one of the features that I'm adding is the ability to add files as attachments (using blobs). On my tests I've added a file of about 60MB and I've noticed that the SQlite UPDATE of a BOOL field of that row is much slower than the others (that are of about 130k).

Doing some tests I've noticed that database file size is the double after the update and also the HDD led is on while is updating, so looks like sqlite is copying the entire row with the new data and then deleting the old, instead just update the field.

For testing pourposes I've created this simple test script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3
import os
from datetime import datetime

# Connect to database
conn = sqlite3.connect(
    "test.sqlite3"
)

# Create table
with conn:
    conn.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Files (
          ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          state BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0,
          Filedata BLOB NOT NULL
        );
        """
    )

print("{}: Adding 60MB file to database".format(datetime.now()))
try:
    with open("60MB.pdf", 'rb') as fIn:
        _blob = fIn.read()
        with conn:
            conn.execute("INSERT INTO Files VALUES (?, ?, ?);", (None, False, sqlite3.Binary(_blob)))
    print("{}: Finished".format(datetime.now()))
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: {}".format(e))


print("{}: Adding 130k file to database".format(datetime.now()))
try:
    with open("130k.pdf", 'rb') as fIn:
        _blob = fIn.read()
        with conn:
            conn.execute("INSERT INTO Files VALUES (?, ?, ?);", (None, False, sqlite3.Binary(_blob)))
    print("{}: Finished".format(datetime.now()))
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: {}".format(e))

print("{}: Updating the state column of 60MB file".format(datetime.now()))
try:
    with conn:
        conn.execute("UPDATE Files SET state = 1 WHERE ID = 1;")
        #conn.execute("UPDATE Files SET state = 0;")
    print("{}: Finished".format(datetime.now()))
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: {}".format(e))

print("{}: Same with 130k file".format(datetime.now()))
try:
    with conn:
        conn.execute("UPDATE Files SET state = 1 WHERE ID = 2;")
        #conn.execute("UPDATE Files SET state = 0;")
    print("{}: Finished".format(datetime.now()))
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: {}".format(e))

conn.close()
#os.remove("test.sqlite3")
```

And with this script I've got this run times:
[image]

Update the 130k row takes about 0.01s, while 60MB row takes about 0.5s (similar to INSERT time).

I think that I understand the problem (every update copy the entire data), so what I've thought is to create a separated table with just and ID and the BLOB, and link both tables using foreign keys for example, but before that, I want to know if maybe I'm doing something wrong and there are better ways.

Someone knows a better way to store big blob data?.

Thanks, and greetings.

Comment: Big blobs should probably be stored as separate files, with the database just holding the path to the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate table for blobs makes sense,
with Foreign Key relationship to base table.
The behavior you're seeing is typical for an RDBMS
that is not a column-store.

> looks like sqlite is copying the entire row with the new data and then deleting the old

Well, not exactly.
Most relational DBs incur some ACID transactional overhead
for such UPDATEs, and sqlite is no exception.
By default it uses journal_mode=WAL, write ahead log.
Sqlite lets you open a pair of connections to your database,
and SELECTs on connection 2 should not see modified values
from connection 1 until it COMMITs the transaction.
This is handled at the row level, and you have very wide rows.
The old row contents are copied to the log,
later a checkpoint happens,
and the boolean within that row receives its new value.
Putting large BLOBs in a separate table as you suggest
will remove the need for such extensive copying.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help. I'll create a separate table to keep the blob unchanged.